# difference between head=newnode and newnode->ptr=head

Tags: c++, linked-list

here is code for insertatstart() fn of a basic linked list. I don't get what is the difference between x->ptr=h and h=x where h is head .explain to me what does each statement do.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
class node{
public:
    int val;
    node*ptr;
};
class linkedlist{
private:
    node*h;
public:
    linkedlist() :h(NULL)
    {}
    void ias(int y)
    {
        node* x = new node;
        x->val = y;
        x->ptr = h;
        h = x;
    }
};
```

Comment: You wrote it, can you not tell us?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about these statements? They're just assignments, no magic happens.

Comment: @grkbb101 Maybe [this drawing](http://pics.c4learn.com/2014/01/insert_start.gif) helps? [(source)](http://www.c4learn.com/data-structure/insert-node-at-first-position-singly-linked-list/)

Comment: i know its wrong but this is what i get from these statements when we do x->ptr= h, x becomes the first node and when we do h=x then h starts pointing to x but since h is ptr of first node and x is the first node h is pointing to itself. so where am i going wrong in my thinking process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`h` is a pointer that should **observe** the head of the list. Assuming that `ias`'s responsability is to insert a new value in front of the list, what happens is as follows:

- you create an unnamed object of type `node` and store its address in the variable `x`;
- you copy the value of `y` into the data member `val` of the unnamed object of type `node` pointed to by `x`;
- you copy the value of `h`, i.e., the address of the first node of the list, into the data member `ptr` of the unnamed object of type `node` pointed to by `x`;
- you say that the pointer `h` should now observe the unnamed object of type `node` pointed to by `x` as the head of the list. You do that by copying the address of the unnamed object of type `node` pointed to by `x` into `h`.

Hope this help.

Comment: your answer has helped.could you please re explain last point in more elaborative way? thanx

Comment: `h` always contains the address of the first object of type `node` in the list (or `nullptr` if no `node` is present). When you insert a new node in front of the list (as you do with the first 3 instructions) you have to update the address stored in `h`, so that it points to the new first object. If you find the answer useful feel free to upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: umm i m trying to but i cant figure out how.could u tell me how do i do that?

Comment: On the right-hand side of the answer you should see a number (zero in this case) within two arrows. Under the bottom arrow there should by a mark on which you can click. By clicking you mark the answer as the accepted one.